# ASP.NET Core using multiple urls in single application

Tags: asp.net-core, url, hosting

I'm creating new ASP.NET Core application and it run on `https://localhost:44382/`. I want to set multiple urls to browse my application like `site1.testing.com, site2.testing.com, site3.tseting.com`.

Everytime I browser those urls , I want to redirect to my application.
I found this setting in `launchSetting.json`

```
 "myCoreApp": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

as you see

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
```

By referencing [this](https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/) ,  I've tried changing in this setting and doesn't work.

Comment: You can point `site1.testing.com` and `site2.testing.com` to one real web application (Use NGINX server block, or Apache HTTP Server virtual host). I belief that, IIS also support this type of configuration. I did this. You can have belief you can do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot declare more than 1 URL for HTTP, and 1 URL for HTTPS protocol. (exclude case: you use different environment parameter).

Recommend for you (also is best practice):

- Use NGINX server block, or
- Apache HTTP Server virtual host.

Reference:

- https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html
- https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/master/src/schemas/json/launchsettings.json#L99